# Windows 10 shared folder

Tags: windows, group-policy, network-share

- ComputerB has a shared folder for backups.
- ComputerA is trying to run Backup and Restore with credentials of a user in ComputerB.

The backup fails because the user is not login in ComputerB.
As soon as I login to ComputerB the backup will succeed.

I need to be able to backup without the need to login to ComputerB. I know there is a policy that handles this but I can't find it.
Do you know the name of the policy?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the [User Rights Assignment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-rights-assignment) there are three and I believe the one you're after, [log on as a batch job](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/log-on-as-a-batch-job)
The GPO Location/Name is:

```
Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\Log on as a batch job
```